# Programmatically invoke click on JLabel

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jlabel

I have a event to listen for mouseclicks on my `JLabel` like:

```
private void jLabel4MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) { 

...

}
```

Is it possible to somehow invoke this programmatically?

And no I do not wish to use a button with `doClick()` :)

Comment: whats JButtons doClick() has to do with something to invokes that, be sure that Icon placed to undecorated JButtons/JToggleButton with doClick() is better than some hacky fireMouseClicked(custom method implemented to MouseAdapter)

Comment: @mKorbel: maybe that should be an answer.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels maybe not, depends of real OPs requirements, maybe JLabel is contianer with JComponents, in this moment / state is my view the same as your,

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need any properties from the `MouseEvent` object then you could just call it with the `null` value. I would suggest though that if you have code that needs to be executed regardless of the click of the button, create a method with the corresponding parameters, call that method from the click handler and then from the other place where you need to call it.

```
private void jLabel4MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) { 
    this.Method(evt.getX(), evt.getY());
}

private void Method(int x, int y) {
  /// bla
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Robot can be made to click anywhere, so yes it's possible. 
Check the [Robot API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) and in particular the `mouseMove(...)`, `mousePress(...)` and `mouseRelease(...)`.

You would need to get the JLabel's screen coordinates first, but this is easily done via its `getLocationOnScreen()` and its `getSize()` method.

I'm curious as to your motivation for this.

Comment: I may be wrong but I think this solution is way too complex--I think the questioner was just asking how to call that method directly--juan's answer is perfect.  This is a good answer but for another question.

Comment: @BillK: You may very well be right, but without further background and context from the original poster, I think that it is too early to tell. I agree that Juan's answer is very good (although I would create a MouseEvent object and would not pass in null), and I have up-voted it.

Comment: I only downvoted yours because i didn't want it pulling attention from juan's (At the time this outranked his)--will revert it if I'm wrong :)  In general I detest downvotes.

Comment: @BillK: I figured as much. The vote really doesn't matter to me at this point.

Comment: +1 based on real skills and probably HFOEs endless curiosity, btw my too